# how to get measurement of the length of shoulder, arm in java?

Tags: java, bluej

this is my image link:

http://compsci.ca/v3/download.php?id=9165&sid=8b1ef1788c32286c495e956bc6cd2df3

i have detect the white string on the body, and get the length. my problem is how to detect the shoulder, then get the measurement of the shoulder and the length or the arm.. please help me :(

this is my work. if there is any correction, please do so and suggest me how to improve my program..

```
import java.io.*;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class GetPixelColor
{
    private static int maxCnt;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        File file= new File("image.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int array[][] = new int [300][400];


           for(int i=0; i<300; i++)
           {
               for(int j=0; j<400; j++)
               {
                   // Getting pixel color by position x=j and y=j
                   int clr=  image.getRGB(j,i); 
                   int  red   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                   int  green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
                   int  blue  =  clr & 0x000000ff;

                  //System.out.println("..................................");
                  //System.out.println("Red Color value = "+ red);
                  //System.out.println("Green Color value = "+ green);
                  //System.out.println("Blue Color value = "+ blue);
                  //System.out.println("..................................");

                  if((red >= 160 && red <= 200) && (green >= 160 && green <= 190) && (blue >= 160 && blue <= 180))//cari kaler
                  {
                      //if(red > 160 && green > 160 && blue > 180)
                      // System.out.print("{"+j+"||"+i+"[0]}");
                          array[i][j] = 0;
                          System.out.print("0");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            array[i][j] = 1;
                            System.out.print("-");
                        }
               }
               System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println(array[0].length);
            System.out.println(array.length);
            int x2 = 0;
            int y2 = 0;
            for (int i = (400-1); i >= 0; i--)//
            {
                for(int j = (300-1); j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[j][i]);
                    if(array[j][i] == 0)
                    {
                        //System.out.print("position2 : x="+i+" y="+j);
                        x2 = i;
                        y2 = j;
                        i = -1;
                        break;

                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"coordinate : \n" + "x : " + x2 +"\n y : "+ y2);
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <400; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[j][i]);
                    if(array[j][i] == 0)
                    {
                        //System.out.print("position1 : x="+i+" y="+j);
                        x = i;
                        y = j;
                        i = 400;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"coordinate : \n" + "x : " +x+"\n y : "+y);

            double m = 0.0;

            m = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y-y2,2) + Math.pow(x-x2,2));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"length of the string : "+m);
            double ratio = 0;
            ratio = m/10;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ratio per inch : " + ratio);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similar marker on the shoulder as the white string on the front. Maybe in a different colour - this makes it easier to distinguish from the white marker in the front.
Once you have detected the shoulder-marker, it should be easy to calculate the length (similar to what you have done for the white string).